# そう when used with past tense of a verb

Tags: word-choice

There are 2 variants of そう. First variant, adds a "looks like/ feels like/ seems like" flavour whereas the second variant adds a "heard from" flavour or hearsay if you like (伝聞).

The question is, when appending そう to the past tense of a verb, it is always the second variant (hearsay). For example:

足を折ったそう - (I heard he) broke his leg

How then, would I say it looks like he broke his leg (just a gut feeling)?

Comment: You may want to re-think this question. You have the two kinds of そう the wrong way round.

Comment: @user3856370 thanks, updated

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, when appending そう to the past tense of a verb, it is always the first variant (feels like). For example:
>
> 足を折ったそう - It looks like he broke his leg (maybe because of his limping)

No, it is never that one. The looks one follows an adjective without the i, and the i form of the verb: 美味しそう = looks delicious, 彼なら作りそう = "someone like him should be able to make it". If it's after the past tense it's the hearsay one. "彼が作ったそうです" = "supposedly he made it".

> How then, would I say I heard he broke his leg (伝聞 / hearsay)? Would adding a だ at the end do the trick in turning it into hearsay?

You've already arrived at your destination.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like I got it the other way round. How then does one use そう with the past tense of a verb to imply "looks like" rather than hearsay?

Comment: In that case you put the following verb in the past.

Comment: What do you mean by putting the following verb in the past? Doesn't that make the hearsay rather than the "looks like"?

Comment: @Ben Do you mean something like 「足が折れそうだった」? Wouldn't that mean 'It looked like his leg was going to break'? I think OP is looking for something like 「足が折れたようだ」 ...

Comment: @Aeon Akechi - No, I meant to say 足が折れそうだった. "It looked like he was going to break his leg". Whether that is correct Japanese or not is another matter.